How do I place two different figures next to each other at the same height?
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle, fill, s sep=1cm,inner sep=1.5pt}
[[[[][]][[][[][]]]][[][[][]]]]
\end{forest}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,
column sep={1.5cm,between origins},
row sep={2.2cm,between origins},
nodes={circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
{
    & & &  |(1)|  &   \\
    & & |(2)|  &  & |(3)|  &  \\
    &  & |(4)|  &  \\
    &  &  &  &  |(5)| &\\};
\draw (1)--(2);
\draw (1)--(3);
\draw (2)--(3);
\draw (2)--(4);
\draw (3)--(4);
\draw (4)to[bend right](5);
\draw (4)to[bend left](5);
\draw (3)--(5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


The left one should be a little higher or the right one further down.
Could anyone help me, please?

exactly what should be aligned? you can specify any node as the baseline, basically, but I'm unclear which it should be in each case.

please make your code compilable so we don't have to guess how to complete it. right now, a minimal attempt will give errors due to missing libraries etc.

You can use baseline to align any pair of nodes from the tree and the picture. I don't know which you might want to align here, so this is by way of illustration only. Substitute the nodes you wish to align for those I've selected below.
The following aligns the root's first child in the forest with the node 2 in the tikzpicture.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle, fill, s sep'=1cm,inner sep=1.5pt},
!r1.baseline,
[[[[][]][[][[][]]]][[][[][]]]]
\end{forest}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,->,baseline=(2)]
\matrix  [%
matrix of math nodes,
column sep={1.5cm,between origins},
row sep={2.2cm,between origins},
nodes={circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt},
]
{
& & &  |(1)|  &   \\
& & |(2)|  &  & |(3)|  &  \\
&  & |(4)|  &  \\
&  &  &  &  |(5)| &\\
};
\draw (1)--(2);
\draw (1)--(3);
\draw (2)--(3);
\draw (2)--(4);
\draw (3)--(4);
\draw (4)to[bend right](5);
\draw (4)to[bend left](5);
\draw (3)--(5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\pagestyle{empty}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

